# Loading elementos da pagina, incluindo textos e não somente imagens como no lazyload

Tags: css, ajax, css3

Pode parecer uma pergunta estupida, mas como faço esse tipo de loading? Tem algum nome especifico? Carrega os textos junto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja esses exemplos: https://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html https://kyusuf.com/post/fake-it-til-you-make-it-css **Repositório** https://github.com/zalog/placeholder-loading

Comment: As respostas para esse link não são exatamente o que eu precisava, o lazyload identificado no link é muito especifico para imagens. O @luís-almeida postou abaixo, exatamente a respeito da minha duvida.